# Is there a way to import main project to iMessage extension?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'd like to re-use my models, and other classes such as networking to my iMessage extension. I couldn't import my "PorjectName", but I could do import pods framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause and a solution for this question.

**Cause:**

The classes of the iMessage extension, by default, isn't has no target membership pointing to the main project, hence the unreadable classes of the main project from the extension classes.

**Solution:**

For each new file created in iMessage Extension, make sure its **Target Membership** has a check mark on your main project! Voila!